# graph mapping resources semaphores

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

hello my friend i have this example i dont understand the solution:
this is the problem:

Are 3 processes P1, P2, P3, which perform three operations on semaphores, S1, S2, S3 with initial values​​: S1 = 1,
S2 = 1, S3 = 1. Knowing that each process executes the following sequence within a loop, to indicate whether any possibility to stay in state interbloqueig. If so, prove it by a graph mapping resources, besides indicating the order in which instructions are executed.

```
        **P1**                 **P2**                   **P3**
        P(s1)                   P(s3)                     P(2)
        P(s3)                   P(s2)                 the critical section
   the critical section         P(s1)                     V(s2)
        V(s3)               the critical section
        V(s1)                   V(s1)
                                V(2)
                                V(3)
```

like solition i have this:
i think that is not correct!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant P(s2) instead of P(2) at the start of P3, and the R's in your graph refer to the semaphores w/ the same number, your graph describes the situation when all 3 processes are at the instruction before its critical section; and since there is a loop (P2->R1->P1->R2->P2), you've got deadlock.  So I guess all that's needed to complete this homework is to list the sequence of instructions executed to get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I guessed that *stay in state interbloqueig* refers to deadlock; deadly embrace. A google seems to confirm this. But please use English next time.  :)

Basically P3 is a red herring because it is only interested in S2. The deadlock involves S1 and S3, because they are acquired in opposite order by P1 and P2. Of course P3 is involved in the deadlock, but even if P3 wasn't there, the deadlock between P1 and P2 is still a troublesome condition.

I think you're being asked to show the deadlock scenario using a resource allocation graph (which is what your graph looks like).

I don't think that the graph can **prove** that the given code has a deadlock; but if we already know how the deadlock happens, we can draw the above graph resource allocation graph for that deadlock, and then show that there is a cycle. A cycle indicates a deadlock if the resources are not multiply instantiated, which they are not: S1, S2 and S3 are single, one-instance resources.)  Prove is maybe not the word you are looking for: maybe *illustrate*.

I believe your resource allocation graph correctly shows that P1 holds resource R3 (i.e. S3) and that P2 holds resource R1 (i.e. S1) and it also shows that P1 wants to acquire R1 while P2 wants to acquire R3 thereby illustrating the cycle that corresponds to the deadlock.